# HTML input autocomplete not working in Electron

Tags: html, electron

I'm building some SocketIO-related app with Electron and React.
The user needs to fill in an address to connect to:

```
<form autoComplete="on" onSubmit={this.onAddressSubmit}>
       <label htmlFor="address">Connect to:</label>
       <input id="address" name="address" onChange={this.onAddressChange} value={this.state.address} type="text" />
       <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For some reason, the autocomplete suggestions do not show up when i run this with Electron, but **do** work when i run it with a "normal" Chrome browser.

Any suggestions as to what can be done? Does Electron put some limitations on purpose?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an open issue on this in electron's github, so you could request it there. I suspect the field autocomplete stuff comes from a part of Chrome/Chromium that not included in Electron or isn't open source.

Comment: @i.brod did you solve the issue?